# Show that $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{n_i - 1}{n_i + 1} \leq \frac{\left(\prod_{i=1}^N n_i \right) - 1}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^N n_i \right) + 1}$

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm not a mathematician but I came across the inequality $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{n_i - 1}{n_i + 1} \leq \frac{\left(\prod_{i=1}^N n_i \right) - 1}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^N n_i \right) + 1}$ in some work I am looking at. We have that $n_i \in \mathbb{N}, n_i \geq 2$ for all $i$.

I thought it would be reasonably easy to show by induction, so I started looking at how much each side increases by when going from $N=k$ to $N=k+1$, hoping to show that the increase of the LHS is smaller than that of the RHS so you would still know the inequality holds, but this has been fruitless so far. Is there some easy way to show this? I've verified it numerically and it seems to hold for any combination of $N$ and $n_i$'s I throw at it, but I can't seem to prove it. Does anybody know the best way to go about showing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove this using the [Jensen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

The function $f(x) = \dfrac{x-1}{x+1}$ is concave (and increasing in $\mathbb{R}_+$). Hence by Jensen inequality, you have :
$$\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N f(n_k) \leq f\left(\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Na_k\right)$$
And since $f$ is also increasing, you have
$$ f\left(\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Na_k\right) \leq f\left(\prod_{k=1}^Na_k\right)$$
We have proven that :
$$ \dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N f(n_k) \leq f\left(\prod_{k=1}^Na_k\right) \square$$

Comment: Note that the AM-GM inequality is the other way around. However, $\frac 1N \sum_{k=1}^Na_k \le \prod_{k=1}^Na_k$ is correct for $a_k \ge 1$.

Comment: Oh yes my bad, I'll change that

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!

Comment: @TheFuser does Jensen's inequality still hold for a function similar to above but if we had $1/N^2$, rather than $1/N$?

Comment: It would if we had $N^2$ terms in the sum.
(More generally, the Jensen inequality works with expressions of the following form : $\sum_{k=1}^{m} a_kf(n_k)$ with $\sum_{k=1}^m a_k = 1$, for instance in my solution we have $a_1 = \ldots = a_N = \dfrac{1}{N}$)


However, if the only modified variable is $\dfrac{1}{N}$ (changed to $\dfrac{1}{N^2})$, you could just say : $$ \dfrac{1}{N^2}\sum_{k=1}^N a_k f(n_k) \leq \dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N a_k f(n_k)$$ and then apply Jensen inequality, as long as your sum is positive.

Hope this helps

Comment: @TheFuser Ah this is for a different but related and similar inequality. I have another function $g(x) = \frac{x}{(x + 1)^2(x + 2)}$ that is convex, and I want to show that $\frac{\prod_{i=1}^N n_i}{\left(\left(\prod_{i=1}^N n_i\right) + 1\right)^2 \left(\left(\prod_{i=1}^N n_i \right) + 2\right)} \leq \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{n_i}{(n_i + 1)^2 (n_i + 2)}$. I thought to do it a similar way using Jensen but because we have the $\frac{1}{N^2}$ term I suppose it will need to be solved another way?

Comment: Yes I think it must be solved differently, or at least need some additional steps: $g$ is convex and decreasing on $[2;+\infty[$: By Jensen's inequality you have :
$$ \dfrac{1}{N^2} \sum_{k=1}^N g(n_k) \geq \dfrac{1}{N} g\left(\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}n_k\right) = RH$$
So you would either directly prove $RH \geq g\left(\prod_{k=1}^N n_k\right)$, or need to find a certain function $d$ of $s=\sum_{k=1}^Nn_k$ such that :
$$ RH \geq g\left(d(s)\right) $$
and such that $d(s) \leq \prod_{k=1}^N n_k$, hence concluding that $g(d(s)) \geq g\left(\prod_{k=1}^N n_k\right)$

Comment: @TheFuser Thanks for the tip! I'll think about it over the weekend and if I'm not able to come up with something I'll post it as another question.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

Since for naturals $n_i$ we have $$\frac{n_1+n_2+...+n_{N}}{N}\leq\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^nn_i+\prod\limits_{i=1}^nn_i+...+\prod\limits_{i=1}^nn_i}{N}=\prod\limits_{i=1}^nn_i,$$ by C-S we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{n_i-1}{n_i+1}=\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{n_i-1}{n_i+1}-1+1\right)\right)=\frac{1}{N}\left(N-2\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{n_i+1}\right)\leq$$
$$\leq\tfrac{1}{N}\left(N-\tfrac{2\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N1\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^N(n_i+1)}\right)=1-\tfrac{2N}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^N(n_i+1)}=1-\tfrac{2}{\tfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^Nn_i}{N}+1}\leq1-\tfrac{2}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^Nn_i+1}=\tfrac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^Nn_i-1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^Nn_i+1}.$$